# How to create a composer for travis build testing

Tags: php, github, travis-ci, php-7.1

I am trying to add the `build-passing` status to my repo using travis. I have been following the the [tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/php/) on the site.

My current `.travis.yml` file looks like this:

```
language: php

php:
  - 7.0
  - 7.1
  - 7.2

matrix:
  include:
    - php: 7.2
      dist: precise

sudo: false

before_script: composer install
script: phpunit
```

My composer looks like this:

```
{
    "name": "ArrayList",
    "description": "A simple library for arrays to use lambda.",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Jaquarh/ArrayList",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Kyle Jeynes",
            "email": "okaydots@gmail.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Jaquarh\\ArrayList\\": "test"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": " 4.8.35"
    }
}
```

However, when I start the build on my repo, it fails with this error

> The command "phpunit" exited with 2.

The raw output (if useful looks like this)

```
0.59s$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master https://github.com/Jaquarh/ArrayList.git Jaquarh/ArrayList
Cloning into 'Jaquarh/ArrayList'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 59, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (59/59), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
remote: Total 59 (delta 27), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (59/59), done.
$ cd Jaquarh/ArrayList
$ git checkout -qf 3876173647ec1f766fabafdf2c5c85d1b2af781e
0.02s$ phpenv global 7.1 2>/dev/null
pearrc
Writing /home/travis/.pearrc
0.30s0.21s$ pear config-show
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/docs
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1.11/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20160303
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/share/pear
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /tmp/pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /tmp/pear/install
directory
Systems manpage files          man_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/man
directory
PEAR metadata directory        metadata_dir     <not set>
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1.11/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1.11/etc/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /tmp/pear/install
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            2
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1.11/etc/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /home/travis/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/7.1.11/etc/pear.conf
0.02s$ phpenv global 7.1
1.34s$ composer self-update
Updating to version 1.8.0 (stable channel).
   Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (100%)
Use composer self-update --rollback to return to version 1.5.2
$ php --version
PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2017 16:25:55) ( ZTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.11, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
$ composer --version
Composer version 1.8.0 2018-12-03 10:31:16
8.06s$ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.2.0 but your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement.
The command "composer install" failed and exited with 2 during .
Your build has been stopped.
```

The documentation states I need to create a composer for travis to execute my instructions. I assuming this is like a 'test'.

I created a new file which includes all of the library and does a test which looks like this inside `test/travis.php`:

```
require_once '../ArrayList.php';

$myArray = new ArrayList([
    ['id' => 1, 'username' => 'foo', 'privilidges' => ['can_read' => 1, 'can_write' => 0], 'incomming' => ''],
    ['id' => 2, 'username' => 'bar', 'privilidges' => ['can_read' => 1, 'can_write' => 1], 'incomming' => 'Hi everyone!']
]);

$myArray->where(function($x) {
    $privilidges = (object) $x['privilidges'];
    return $privilidges->can_write;
})->getFirstOrDefault()
  ->ifPresent(function($x) {
      if(!empty(($incomming = $x['incomming']))) echo $incomming;
  });
```

However, this is not a composer and I have no clue how to make Travis execute this.

Any ideas or help would be appreciated, this is my first time using Travis and the documentation isn't helping with reference to creating test environments for travis to build against.

[This is my repository](https://github.com/Jaquarh/ArrayList) if looking at it is any help.

After updating my composer to use PHP 7.1.11 I get this error

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Comment: Is the error message unclear? "This package requires php >=7.2.0 but your PHP version (7.1.11) does not satisfy that requirement." Your `composer.json` explicitly requires PHP 7.2 but you're trying to use PHP 7.1. Either change your `composer.json` or upgrade PHP.

Comment: Actually, I've been working on this all day and just got it working. **Yes**, that error is technically self explanatory but by changing the PHP version, it just gave me more error messages about using 7.2, or 7.1.11 etc.. Once I fixed this, like it states at the end of the OP, i got another error about installable set of packages. I answered my own question anyway because it needed more fixing than what you said @Chris

Comment: Check the composer bugtracking system. Composer fixed a bug that caused it to not reject some broken setups. Upgrading then caused these setups to fail.

Comment: The problem wasn't in my composer by the looks of things, Travis expects a dependency to use as a testing service, therefor I had to create a PHPUnit test script which then fixed all the build errors @UlrichEckhardt thanks for your help though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure out what is required for PHPUnit and the composer.

I changed my `.travis.yml` to test all PHP versions and execute the script required to run tests.

```
language: php

php:
  - 5.4
  - 5.5
  - 5.6
  - 7.0
  - 7.1
  - 7.2

matrix:
  include:
    - php: 5.3
      dist: precise

sudo: false

before_script: composer install
script: phpunit
```

The test required configuration, so in a new file `phpunit.xml.dist` I put this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="PHP ArrayList Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Next, I created a script for this configuration to go with called `run-tests.sh`:

```
php --version
php phpunit.phar --configuration phpunit.xml.dist
```

I updated my composer to use PHP 5.3 as a start like so:

```
{
    "name": "ArrayList",
    "description": "A simple library for arrays to use lambda.",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/Jaquarh/ArrayList",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Kyle Jeynes",
            "email": "okaydots@gmail.com",
            "role": "Developer"
        }
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Jaquarh\\ArrayList\\": "src"
        }
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": " 4.8.35"
    }
}
```

Finally, I built the tests which included `bootstrap.php` and `autoload.php.dist`:

```
if (file_exists($file = __DIR__ . '/autoload.php')) {
    require_once $file;
} elseif (file_exists($file = __DIR__ . '/autoload.php.dist')) {
    require_once $file;
}

// if the library is the project, try to use the composer's autoload for the tests
$composerAutoload = __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

if (is_file($composerAutoload)) {
    include $composerAutoload;
} else {
    die('Unable to find autoload.php file, please use composer to load dependencies:

wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
php composer.phar install

Visit http://getcomposer.org/ for more information.

');
}
```